# Authenticating user with PassportJS and passport-linkedin-oauth2 strategy gives ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error

Tags: node.js, oauth, linkedin-api, passport.js

So far I've gotten boilerplate authentication with PassportJS and the passport-linkedin-oauth2 strategy to redirect me to a page on LinkedIn that returns an ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error.  The URL that's redirected to is:

`https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&redirect_uri=MY_CALLBACK_URL&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_fullprofile%20r_contactinfo%20rw_groups%20r_network&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID`

When the redirect happens, LinkedIn's servers return a 330 error of 
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED, which isn't what I expected to happen.  I've registered my app and gotten the keys from the developers section.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: I did, and it was a simple misconfiguration error.  The key being used in the Strategy configuration for clientID was the Client Secret Key, when it needed to be the API Key.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. May be useful to create this as an answer to make it clearer to others.